# WCF-based federated security in a service-oriented setup

Tags: wcf, security, token, layered, federated

So i have the following scenario:

I have a WPF-application which includes a login-box.
Users enter credentials, which is used to get a security token from a SecurityTokenService (STS).
This token is parsed to a backend web-service, and in this way the service authenticates the user. Since the binding between client and webservice is a wsFederationHttpBinding this happens pretty seemless.

Now my problem is that I, from the webservice, needs to call another webservice which is also protected by federated security, expecting security-tokens from the same STS.

So essentially what I would like to do is to re-use the security token given from the client, in order to carry the users security-token to the second webservice.

I have found a way to create a WCF-channel to the second service, by providing a securitytoken, which is a common approach when caching security tokens.
However I am having trouble finding a way of getting a hold on the security token, from the client, in the backend webservice.

Anyone with any experience in parsing a security-token in a multi-layered setup?

Answer (score 0):

You've just hit one of the most common issues with wsFederationHttpBinding.
There is a sample on MSDN for a [durable issued token provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717045%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) that should help.

> This sample shows how to build a custom token provider that caches tokens issued by a Security Token Service (STS).